# What is the point of prefixing function names with '_' React/React-native ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So as per convention since JavaScript doesn't have access modifiers I have to prefix "private" function names with an underscore(_). But I am a little confused here, say I am writing a class in C++ or Java that has two functions one that performs internal calculations and the second that returns the result of that internal calculation.

So, I have these two functions

```
performInternalSecretCalculation();
getResult();
```

the `performInternalSecretCalculation()` is supposed to be private since I don't want other classes to worry about how the class handles calculation and hence I don't export this function. Whereas `getResult()` is something that will be used by other classes and hence I make it public and export this function.

But in case of React classes I am not exporting any functions all the functions defined inside a react class are used within it. So what is the differentiator? When should I prefix an underscore before a function's name?

Comment: "*supposed to be private since I don't want other classes to worry about how the class handles calculation*" - um, no, that's not why you want to make it private. The purpose of *all* methods is to hide the implementation. Only if you don't want others to *call* the method (in your case: trigger the calculation), you make it private.

Comment: @Bergi "not supposed to worry about" implied I don't want other classes to call this method, sorry if that's not clear in the text

Comment: It was the word "worry … *how*" that struck me - maybe you want to [edit] the text

Comment: Can you show a code example in your React Example? The underscore is pure convention, there is no way to implement a private access modifier in ES6 in the classical OOP sense, although there are plenty of alternatives. However, ```CustomClass.compute()``` and a private ```compute()``` function scoped inside a class are two different implementations we could suggest help with.

Comment: If you can, move the private candidates out of the class body and make them module scope. It won't take much to pass on all the relevant context data to makeup for the loss of context on a class method.

Answer (score 23):

It is just a naming convention, used by some developers for internal methods to separate them from the lifecycle methods of react.

### Lifecycle methods

- constructor
- getChildContext
- componentWillMount
- componentDidMount
- componentWillReceiveProps
- shouldComponentUpdate
- componentWillUpdate
- componentDidUpdate
- componentWillUnmount

List is borrowed from the [AirBnB Style Guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/react/README.md#ordering).

### Airbnb React/JSX Style Guide

I prefer the [Style Guide from AirBnB](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/react/README.md#methods). They suggest not to use underscore prefix.
I force instead a clean order for the methods.

Comment: React life cycle methods are only a handful, they mostly don't bloat the component code much. I also don't prefer an underscore, name them the same way as any other method. I do keep the methods in alphabetical order for readability.